# Is it safe to save a authenticated user info in window

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am using laravel vue. In my first page load, I try to assign the auth user like this. In my blade file I use

```
<script>

    (function () {
        window.Laravel = {
            csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        };


        @if(Auth::check())
          window.user={!! Auth::user() !!}
         @else
            window.user=false
         @endif
    })();
  </script>
```

My question is, can user manipulate this window somehow from the browser? 
I don't use this directly instead I use it from vuex.

Many thanks.

Comment: The user can manipulate *everything* that you send them.

Comment: I meant, lets say, user.id = 25 can they change user.id = 55 I tried to change but it didn't work from the browser.

Comment: Nope, actually user can change window.user object

Comment: Yes, they can change anything in the code that runs in their browser. But what does it matter? Your server won't send them sensitive data for a user id that they aren't authenticated as, right?

Comment: But there are some logics if user is logged or not in vue app and thats done via v-if so I see I have to make ajax calls to load authenticated data :( 

is there any other way to do this?

Comment: As long as any sensitive data is `Auth::check()`ed on the server, there's nothing wrong with doing some additional logics on the client side.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Security isn’t something you should be asking, “Could I get away with doing _just_ this…?” No. You should be doing _everything_ you can to authorise users and validate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can change the contents of `window.user`, but that shouldn't matter: It's your task to validate any data the user sends back to the server. For example, your view might contain a form to change the username. You *could* do it this way:

```
// View
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: {
    username: 'New Name',
    id: id,
  }
});

// Controller
$user = User::find(request('id'));
$user->name = request('username');
$user->save();
```

That'd be a bad idea as the user could use the form to change *any* users name. Instead, get the current user in the controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->name = request('username');
$user->save();
```

Also, I wouldn't put authentication logic in a Blade file. Instead, I'd prepare the relevant data inside a controller and pass it to the view (something like `return view('user.show', compact('user'));`)

Comment: Yap make sense but lets say there is a front end logic for a role, now user can easily change role and v-if will also change..

Comment: There's no `v-if` in your code example. `@if`is interpreted server side. If a guest visits the page, all the elements of the view that are for registered users only shouldn't even be part of the page source that's sent to the browser. If you *are* logged in every attempt to change data that belongs to other users should be refused by the server.

Comment: Thanks got it. Never trust client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can manipulate.

Please don't be lazy about implementing backend validation on your backend side.